# Linkage Incompatible

Tags: c++

I've got a C++ library where I'm trying to export some methods so they can be used in another C# application. At the top of my header file, I've got the following:

```
extern "C" {
  __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl initSamplers();
  __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl ldbnBNOT(const unsigned int nbPts, std::vector<Point>& samples);
}
```

However, my intellisense tells me that I have an error in the declaration of the ***ldbnBNOT*** method. The error states, "linkage specification is incompatible with previous "ldbnBNOT" (declared in line 79)". In this same header file, but farther down below on line 79 I have this method:

```
extern void __cdecl ldbnBNOT(const unsigned int nbPts,
              std::vector<Point> &samples)
{
  samples.clear();
  auto n = std::floor(std::sqrt((double)nbPts));
  Point p;

  double inv = 1.0 / n;
  unsigned mask = 128 - 1;                                                      
  unsigned shift = std::log2(128);
  for (unsigned Y = 0; Y < n; Y++) {
    for (unsigned X = 0; X < n; X++) {
      unsigned index = ((Y & mask) << shift) + (X & mask);
      double u = phi( (Y & 0xfffffff0) + (lutLDBN_BNOT[index] & 0xf) );
      double v = phi( (X & 0xfffffff0) + (lutLDBN_BNOT[index] >> 4) );
      p[0] = inv * (X + u);
      p[1] = inv * (Y + v);
      samples.push_back(p);
    }
  }
}
```

The signature in the __cdecl ldbnBNOT matches the same signature as the extern method... But I don't understand why I'm still getting this linker error.

Comment: Can you try and reduce the complexity of the function type until it doesn't fail any more. Clearly the one without arguments appears to be fine. I'm not versed in this, but I have no idea what happens to `std::vector` if you wrap it in an `extern "C"`, for example.

Comment: You should try and express that in C terms, as in `Point*` instead. You'll also need a `size_t` size hint argument.

Comment: you may be right... I tried only using a single argument (unsigned int) and it works fine... but if I change the signature to only use a single argument of std::vector<Point> then it fails again... any thoughts why?

Comment: C doesn't know what a vector is, nor a reference.

Comment: @tadman should it look like this? _extern void __cdecl ldbnBNOT(const unsigned int nbPts, Point* samples,  size_t size)_ Because this still tells me that I still have a linker error if I use these arguments in both the function declarations.

Comment: That's a good C method signature, so long as it's actually exported as that. Can you export a list of symbols from your compiled library? Make sure C# is looking for a C method, not C++.